# Encore CS6 "DualLayer: This disc requires a layer break"

Tags: encore

I am trying to create a dual-layer 8.5 GB DVD image.

It consists of an MPEG multiplexed video with audio and Encore chapter markers created in Premiere Pro CS6 and does not require transcoding in Encore, occupying about 1.69 GB of space.

I also have ROM content where I have two HD video files, with one of them 5.63 GB in size.

Now when I run `Check Project`, Encore does not show any warnings, however when I try to build the DVD image, it fails with the message

```
DualLayer: This disc requires a layer break
```

I have tried both the `Automatic` and the `Manual` layer break setting, and I do not see where and how I could set a manual break in Encore.

So, my question is, how do I make this work, what are my options ?
Is this issue because the 5.63 GB file cannot fit onto one layer (why would this even matter) ?

Comment: Could you just put all of your files into premiere onto a timeline, and then export them as an MPEG and then chapter it in Encore? I don't know if it's the best fix but seems like a workaround. I don't have much experience with burning dual layer discs.

Comment: Well, there is only one video on the DVD Video portion of the disc, which consists of one MPEG file only. So you mean I should re-encode the video without Encore chapter markers and instead create them in Encore ? Where can I find this info that this may fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to create a DVD DL with a ROM part that exceeds a layer's size.

So I created a 4 GB HD video (which also fits on a FAT32 file system) and created a DL disc with some GBs wasted space.

I tried to put another file onto the ROM part but this always fails as soon as the ROM part exceeds the layer limit, which is strange because DVD-ROM-only DL discs seem to work perfectly.